# Fluent Bit set index mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, fluentd, elk, fluent-bit

I am trying to set all mapped fields to string ie if a json message comes with following:

```
{
    "logDate": "2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z",
    "logId": 123131,
    "message": {
       "username": "pera",
       "password": "pera123"
    }
}
```

I need to log every value as string ie. logId should be logged as `"logId": "123131"`.

Is there a way to tell fluent bit what index mapping to use of maybe there is another setting that changes dynamic type to string?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe can try adding an index template.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-templates.html